# IE caching the ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, internet-explorer, servlets

I have a situation that IE is caching the Ajax request. I am able to fix the Issue my specially saying `response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");` in my Servlet. I see  that this statement`response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");`also do the same thing. Which is the best method should i us?

Comment: have you looked at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)?

Comment: Yes i did. When Dev explained it made sense than reading the Doc:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");` as that is the only value you want the header to have. `addHeader(String, String)` is used when the header can have multiple values assigned to it.